# SQL Server Update Statistics

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 questions about SQL Server statistics, please help me. I am using SQL Server 2016.

My table `TBL1` has only one column `COL1`. When I used `COL1` in joins with other tables, statistics are automatically created on `COL1`.

Next I create a non-clustered index on `COL1` of `TBL1`, then another set of statistics are created on `COL1`. Now I have 2 sets of statistics on `COL1`.

1. Out of the above 2 statistics, which statistics are used by SQL Server for further queries? I am assuming that the statistics created by the non-clustered index will be used, am I right?
2. If I use the `Update Statics TBL1` command, all the statistics for `TBL1` are updated. In the MSDN documentation, I see that updating statistics causes queries to recompile, what do they mean by re-compiling of queries? The MSDN link is
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/update-statistics?view=sql-server-ver15

Please explain.

Comment: This question seems too broad/junclear/duplicate. First of all, it's asking 2 questions in one. Then the 1st probably depends on what your "further queries" are. And the 2nd seems like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972387/sql-server-statistics-and-recompiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only 1 column in your table, there's no reason to have a non-clustered index.  This creates a separate copy of that data.  Just create the clustered index on that column.

1. *Yes* - Since your table only has the one column and an index was created on that column, it's almost certain that SQL Server will use that index whenever joining to that table and thus the statistics for that index will be used.
2. In this context, it means that the execution plan in cache will be invalidated due to stale statistics and the next time a query executes the optimizer will recreate an execution plan. In other words, it will be assumed there may be a better set of steps to execute the query and the optimizer will try to assemble a better set of steps (execution plan) to execute.

Recommended Reading:

- [SQL Server Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Understanding Execution Plans](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-query-execution-plan-beginners-types-options/)
- [Execution Plan Caching & Reuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181055(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)